# Nested getcmsfields_forpopup showing in same popup in silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

I have form in getcmsfields_forpopup for backend(admin panel) in silverstrip. In that form, I have added nested dataobjectmanager field to enter multiple dates(has_many relation). When main form open in popup window and I click on add date link, then second popup form open in the same window not in separate one. That means after entering date data and saving it, when I click on close button, whole form is closed rather going back to main form. Please help in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done using SilverStripe's default popup form unless, maybe, you extended the DataObject Manager field and had it render itself in an iFrame.

The best option would be to manage your parent DataObjects with DataObjectManger as well. DataObjectManager supports nested DataObjectManager fields. See this tutorial "[Nested DataObjectManager](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eeXOTlXFmQQ)" (on YouTube).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Line 70 in [silverstripeinstallation]/saphire/ComplexTableField.js is preventing that to happen. If I comment out that line then I am able to open and resize window but still I can close both forms at once. I followed that tutorial to make that nested popup. Can you please give some more example/reference about how to make complex popup forms.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able, can I suggest that you try out SilverStripe 3.0?  The support for this kind of thing is much better in SilverStripe 3.0 than it is in 2.4.

Comment: Hi, Do SilverStripe 3 supports popup ?

Comment: No, rather than appearing the pop-up, things like the detail forms for a GridField will show in the entire right hand side.  Check out the security section of the demo (http://ss3.demo.silverstripe.org/admin/security/, user: admin, password: password) and open the details of a member to see how it works.